# Why did Albus Dumbledore have planets on his watch?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Why did Albus Dumbledore have planets on his watch? Also, which ones were they?

I have been trying to grasp the reason for having planets as your time markings, but couldn't settle on anything. He used his golden pocket watch many times in the books, all for varied and exclusive reasons that didn't relate with each other.

Comment: There were twelve known planets in the solar system between 1846 and 1851. I assume Dumboedore’s astronomy is a bit behind the times.

Comment: @Trusha_Patel - A planet is defined as, among other things, being large enoguh that its gravity pulls itself into a spheroidal shape, and thus at least a few hunded kilometers in diameter.  So Dumbledore must have been a very powerfull wizard indeed to trasnport 12 planets from outer space and shrink them into his watch, leaving only 8 left in the solar system.  Or did you mean that Dumbledore had images of planets in his watch?

Comment: Well, we know that he can use it to tell the time; https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Albus_Dumbledore%27s_pocket_watch

Comment: Note that the watch had 12 _hands_; I don't believe the number of planets was ever stated.  Perhaps the hands mark fixed increments of time and there are a set of planets that orbit once a minute, once an hour, and once per 12 hours.

Comment: "*"It was a very odd watch. It had **twelve hands** but no numbers; instead, little planets were moving around the edge."*"

Comment: Note that there are at least 2 ways this could work; either with the planets showing time against the fixed hands, or with the hands indicating the divisions of the zodiac and the planets displaying as an orrery.  (Being able to quickly read off conjunctions could be useful for a wizard.)

Comment: Or, you know, one hand is hours and one is minutes, and you don't need numbers to know where they're pointing as long as you have the watch the right way up. The other hands are for other things (lunar phase, zodiac).

Comment: @M.A.Golding Going for some kind of pedantry record?

Comment: I'll be honest when I say that there is very less info about this watch. The watch has been mentioned only twice throughout the entire series for goodness' sake.

Comment: @MikeScott That's interesting. What 12 planets were those, and what happened in 1846 and 1851? Wikipedia tells me that asteroid 5 Astraea was discovered in 1845, the planet Neptune in 1846, and 6 Hebe in 1847. When did they stop counting asteroids as planets?

Answer (score 2):

There is no canon answer.

It seems reasonable to speculate that JK had intended simply to convey at that early juncture at one or both of two things:

- Wizards use very different timepieces than the muggle world does.
- Wizards have significantly more information displayed on their watches, including stellar states.

It may also be possible that Dumbledore, being Dumbledore, had a unique timepiece that he himself used with distinction from everyone else.

The way that wizards keep time versus muggles was likely not more than an early idea that did not transform into something more significant, and was simply dropped or forgotten as the story developed in lieu of your standard West European time system. This kept non-essential distractions out of the already increasingly lengthy plot line.

I will make note here that the Western 24-hour (mod 12) timekeeping scheme is not the only common one in the world today: there are around a dozen other systems still in use around the globe.

Ultimately, however, without more information from Rowling herself there is only speculation.